# Eloquent - Multiple sum on the same relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The models I have are : **Quote** and **Payment**

- A Quote hasMany Payments
- A Payment belongsTo a Quote
- A Payment has an 'amount' and a boolean 'is_received' fields

**I'm trying to make a single query that fetches :**

- **All the Quotes**
- **For each Quote the sum of the received payments amounts**
- **For each Quote the sum of all the payments amount**

What I currently have is the following query... it is missing the sum of the received payments, which I have no idea how to implement (also I'm not sure this is a good approach for get the total sum anyway) :

```
$quotes = Quote::with([
   'payments' => function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('quote_id, SUM(payments.amount) AS payments_total')->groupBy('quote_id');
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use something like this:

```
Quote::with(['payments' => function ($query) {
$query->selectRaw(
    "SUM(amount) AS payments_total," .
    "SUM(IF is_received = " . true . " THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 
received_amount");
}])->get();
```